# Rails and Searchlogic: finding products that matching all given product categories by using searchlogic condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, searchlogic

I have a model Publication and a model Category in my Rails app. Both are connected with a has_and_belongs_to_many association.

Now I would like to search publications that match one or more categories. If more than one  category is given they have all assigned to the publication. I want to specify the categories in a multiple select_box.

`Publication.released.categories_id_is([1,2])` is not working because the categories are connected with OR.

With `Publication.categories_id_is_all([1,2])` the categories are connected with AND, but no result is given back.

Any idea's on that? Am I mising the right point in the docs. Thanks for your very welcome help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the logs to see what SQL query is actually being run for those commands.

You may want to try

```
Publication.categories_id_equals_all([1,2])
```

As the `is` shortcut could be causing a problem there

Comment: I should also note that I've used 'equals_any' with searchlogic before and it has worked as expected but I have not tested 'equals_all' personally